# Breaking stone pipes in ARK: Survival Evolved

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

When building our base, I tried to place a stone pipe intake in a nearby river. However, I misplaced it, and wanted to get rid of it. I wasn't able to damage or destroy it using a stone pick or stone hatchet.

Are pipes indestructible? If no - how can I destroy/recover them?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to approach the pipe and then hold the 'E' key, this will provide the option to demolish the pipe, it will also return half of the materials used to create it back to you.

Note that you must hover over demolish in the wheel for a few seconds until the timer on it counts down, this is a safety feature used by the developers to prevent accidental demolishes

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the demolish feature for other objects, but I couldn't get the selection wheel open. Potentially because it was stuck through the ground, or maybe because I didn't have the proper tribe permissions at the time. Either way, this is the appropriate way to remove things. +1

Comment: Alternatively you can potentially kite a dinosaurs attacks around the pipe area and this may damage it enough to break it. For example a bronto has a large sweeping attack which damages stone pipes. The pipe clipping the ground though is probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Pigram already answered the question in the correct sense. Holding 'E' while the pipe is in focus and selecting Demolish is indeed the best route.

To answer the other question,

> "Are pipes indestructible? If no - how can I destroy/recover them?"

No, they are not indestructible. A stone pipe requires a metal+ tool/weapon to destroy it.

Larger dinos may also stomp right through them from time to time if they are in the way.